# Windows Shortcut with Relative File Path

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, command-line-arguments, file-shortcut

I have created a tool that uses Google Chrome App Mode to work.  In order to access it, I have a shortcut to google chrome that opens the specific html page.  Currently, I have an absolute path, but I as I make copies of the tool for the sake of version history, I have to update the copied shortcut as well.  This is time consuming, and could be prone to errors if I mis-type (luckily it isn't as big of an issue because they're archived versions, but still...)

**Is there a way to use a relative path?**  I tried using `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --app="index.html"` however that doesn't work, and instead of opening a window in app mode (no chrome, just the title bar and the html document), it just opens a new browser window with the new tab page.  It completely ignores the file referenced in in `--app`.

Comment: relative to the lnk file itself?  What do you have in the "start in" field?  That is where chrome's initial directory will be.  Leave that blank.

Comment: Look into the option/switch `--file-url-path-alias` perhaps you can then set part of the base url as an alias i.e. alias is named `foo` and `foo` is set to `versionnumber` and the target is `//baseurl/foo/index.html`. Not sure the proper syntax but check the man pages. Depends on your logical folder structure of course

Comment: Yeah, relative to the lnk file, itself.  So if I move the folder with the app to another directory (where I archive the older versions), it doesn't matter how many folders I put it into, provided the structure of the app folder, itself, remains the same (the location of the html file in relation to the lnk)

Comment: Try `--load-and-launch-app="index.html"`. Leave the "Start In" field empty in the shortcut, for it to run in the current working directory.

Comment: I get the following error: `Failed to load extension from: C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\91.0.4472.164\index.html. Manifest file is missing or unreadable`  It seems that argument is intended to install an app into chrome, as opposed to launching a chrome-less window.  Unless I found the wrong thing when doing a quick google search...